# PWA app beforeInstallPrompt not firing other browseres only fire Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

Inside PWA Reactjs app beforeinstallprompt only fire in Chrome mobile and desktop browser. I want to fire or trigger other browser as Chrome. What i done wrong.

Inside App.js add EventListener with useEffect.

```
   useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
            // Prevent the mini-infobar from appearing on mobile
            e.preventDefault();
            // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
            deferredPrompt = e;
            // Update UI notify the user they can install the PWA
            setInstallable(true);
        });

        window.addEventListener('appinstalled', () => {
            // Log install to analytics
            console.log('INSTALL: Success');
        });
    }, []);
```

But not fire other browsers only fire chrome browser...

Comment: Here is a list of the supported browsers https://caniuse.com/web-app-manifest also here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeinstallprompt` event is only fired in Chrome, Edge, and Samsung Internet currently. Safari allows users to install PWAs, but users have to do it themselves by clicking the Share button, then Add to Home Screen.

Comment: Actually now I don't see it even in Samsung Internet